# jQuery Prevent div's click behavior when inline href is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, live, preventdefault

I have a div containing a href. The div has a jQuery live click event:

```
$(".item").live("click", function() { 
    window.location = this.id;  
});
```

In the div I have a href:

```
<div class="item" id="/test.html">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test" id="123">link</a>
</div>
```

Also with a live click event:

```
$(".test").live("click", function() { 
    $(".item").unbind('click');
    alert(this.id);
});
```

What I try to achieve is click the div loads the div id as location while clicking the link inside the div does it's own thing while preventing the div click behavior.

I know I could take the href out of the div but I don's want that ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

If you can, use jQuery 1.7 to do the event delegation using `.on` and stop the anchor clicks from propagating:

```
$(document).on("click","a.test", function(e) { 
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).on("click","div.item", function(e) { 
    // whatever
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuHjA/3/

Otherwise use `.delegate` instead of `.live`:

```
$(document).delegate("a.test", "click", function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).delegate("div.item", "click", function(e) { 
    //whatever
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AuHjA/4/

Comment: Matt that's because you have it backwards, you need to stop the propagation in the link and not the div  http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/AuHjA/5/. The reason it works in this case is because both parent div and the child element have been bound with `.live` hence `e.stopPropagation()` actually works.